# Scikit-Learn timeseries pipeline with multiple records per date (data in long format)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

I'm looking at a good way to process event-like timeseries data in a Scikit-Learn pipeline.

As an example, we have this kind of data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03'],
    'event': ['new_year', np.nan, np.nan, 'birthday', 'birthday', 'holiday'],
    'value': [0.2, 0.3, np.nan, 0.4, 0.5, np.nan]
}).astype({'date': 'datetime64[D]'})
```

```
| date       | event    |   value |
|:-----------|:---------|--------:|
| 2022-01-01 | new_year |     0.2 |
| 2022-01-02 | nan      |     0.3 |
| 2022-01-02 | nan      |   nan   |
| 2022-01-03 | birthday |     0.4 |
| 2022-01-03 | birthday |     0.5 |
| 2022-01-03 | holiday  |   nan   |
```

I've added the numerical column to show that there are other type of columns as well.

The expected result would be something like this:

```
| date       |   event_new_year |   event_birthday |   event_holiday |   value |
|:-----------|-----------------:|-----------------:|----------------:|--------:|
| 2022-01-01 |                1 |                0 |               0 |    0.2  |
| 2022-01-02 |                0 |                0 |               0 |    0.3  |
| 2022-01-03 |                0 |                1 |               1 |    0.45 |
```

Or another example output, using different aggregation methods:

```
| date       |   event_new_year |   event_birthday |   event_holiday |   value |
|:-----------|-----------------:|-----------------:|----------------:|--------:|
| 2022-01-01 |                1 |                0 |               0 |    0.2  |
| 2022-01-02 |                0 |                0 |               0 |    0.3  |
| 2022-01-03 |                0 |           0.6667 |          0.3333 |    0.5  |
```

Just to be clear, the **intent is not to do this on the entire dataset with Pandas**, but it would have been much nicer to be able to **do this in the Scikit-Learn environment** where data is split in a train/test set, with cross-validation, and in combination with other types of data and transformers/encoders, all set up in a pipeline, etc.

I tried creating a custom transformer ([example](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ksvmuralidhar/creating-custom-transformers-using-scikit-learn/notebook)), and to some extent that works, but it's quite complex and I'm not sure I can make it work within sklearn's pipeline. However, I had expected that such data and goal is pretty common, but I fail in finding information. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you dont want a solution that uses custom transformers ?

Comment: Not per se, I'm wondering what the best way of working is when data is in this format, as I expect this is not very exotic.